# FunSuite missing even though ScalaTest is imported

Tags: scala, scalatest

I want to start writing simple tests in Scala using ScalaTest.
But for some reason, I can access `org.scalatest` but not `org.scalatest.FunSuite`
This is what my `build.sbt` looks like:

```
name := "Algorithms"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.13.3"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.0" % "test"
```

I don't understand if it can access `scalatest` then why are `FunSuite`,`FlatSpec` and other styles missing?

Output of running `test` on `sbt shell`

```
[error] <Project Path>\Algorithms\src\test\scala\Course1\Week1\MaxPairProductTest.scala:3:48: type FunSuite is not a member of package org.scalatest
[error] class MaxPairProductTest extends org.scalatest.FunSuite {
[error]                                                ^
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

ScalaTest 3.2.0 has completed [modularisation](https://www.scalatest.org/release_notes/3.2.0) of the monolith from prior versions

> The main change in ScalaTest 3.2.0 is carrying out the modularization
> that we prepared for in 3.0.8 and 3.1.0. As a result, many deprecated
> names have been removed, because the deprecations would cross module
> boundaries.

This means that whilst in 3.1.0 the following definition

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
 
class ExampleSuite310 extends FunSuite {}
```

would just raise deprecation notice

```
The org.scalatest.FunSuite trait has been moved and renamed. Please use org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuite instead. This can be rewritten automatically with autofix: https://github.com/scalatest/autofix/tree/master/3.1.x", "3.1.0"
```

in 3.2.0 it has been removed entirely. Hence from 3.2.0 onwards you should define like so

```
import org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuite

class ExampleSuite320 extends AnyFunSuite {}
```

See [deprecations expirations](https://www.scalatest.org/release_notes/3.2.0#expiredDeprecations) for full list of new names.

Note we can still import a single artifact which will pull transitively all the sub-artifacts

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.0" % "test"
```

however now we also have the options of depenending on just the particular sub-artifact

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest-funsuite" % "3.2.0" % "test"
```

Comment: Thank You so much. This fixed it. However, why was I not getting that Depracation notice? Not even the website's instruction mentioned this.

Comment: @VarunGawande Deprecation warnings seem to work for me in 3.1.0. Try with `;clean;set Test/scalacOptions += "-deprecation";Test/compile;`. Indeed website seems to be out-of-date in few places, however scaladoc seems to be well maintained. Personally, I keep an eye on https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/releases which should have the most up-to-date information.

Comment: Probably this tutorial from the official documentation for Scala needs an update - https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started/intellij-track/testing-scala-in-intellij-with-scalatest.html :-|